# Volume of tetrahedron.

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $D$ be a tetrahedron with corners $(0,0,0), (2,0,0), (0,6,0), (0,0,4)$. Find the volume of $D$ by setting up a triple integral.
[image]

The equation of the plane containing these points is $$6x+2y+3z-12=0.$$ My question is how do I set up the bounds on the three integrals to get a volume? Thanks for the help.

Comment: take $z$ from $0$ to $12-6x-2y$, e.g.; you could check your answer using Volume=$\dfrac13$Base$\times$Height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general idea is, after picking an order of integration (say $\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}z$), work backwards.

The range where $z$ works (for some possible $x,y$) is going to be from $z=0$ to $3z-12=0$, maximizing $z$ by setting $x=y=0$.

Now, suppose we know $z$ (for the middle integral). What values of $y$ are possible - that's $y=0$ to $2y+3z-12=0$ (solve this equation for $y$).

Finally, for the inner integral, for any given $y,z$, $x$ itself ranges from $0$ to whatever the maximum is solved for.

Comment: Thanks. I got $8$.

Comment: The direct answer is $2\cdot4\cdot6/3!$ so that's correct

Comment: @squenshl, have you even read the thread so the users don't waste, both their and your time, answering abstract duplicates?

Comment: I consider "how to set up the integral" sufficiently distinct as a question that wasn't focused on in the answer to the duplicate, since this is not the unit tetrahedron

Comment: _since this is not the unit tetrahedron_ just proves it's an abstract duplicate. You can't say without reading the body and all of the answers there.

Comment: None of the answers and comments there actually answer the question "okay I have an equation for a plane, how do I actually get the limits to the triple integral" which is precisely OP's question. In other words "does this answer your question?" - to me, **no**

Comment: The point of associating questions with the previous ones isn't finding the answer to just one sentence, but learning more on the whole concept. You can find certain answers in more than one post and the questions shouldn't always be narrow: narrow $\ne$ exact. The princips matter, at least that is what I can say based on my personal experience. I won't extend these comments. Have a nice day & a lot of math!

Answer (score 1):

if coordinate of  vertices are given then volume of tetrahedron is obtained by the below written formula
vol= determinant value of determinant with  first row 1,0,0,0second row 1,4,0,0 third row1,0,6,0and fourth row1,0,0,2. I can't type determinant in smartphone so I answered like this